# How to change web service URL in JBoss 5.1

Tags: jboss, web-services, ejb

Environment:
Windows 2003
JBoss 5.1

Code:

```
@WebService
@Stateless
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public class MyWebService {
public String sayHello() {
return "Hello";
}
}
```

wsdl is deployed in:
`http://localhost:8080/ear-project-ejb-project/MyWebService?wsdl`

I would like to define another path for this webservice, something like:

`http://localhost:8080/MyApplication/MyWebService?wsdl`

How to configure that in JBoss 5.1? Is there some kind of configuration that will work in any Java EE server?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you set such Java EE configuration in the web.xml file of your web(service) project:

```
<display-name>MyApplication</display-name>

<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>MyWebService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.my.company.my.package.MyWebServiceEndPoint</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```